# Installing Ubuntu on a Dell Laptop Error

Tags: boot, dual-boot, dell

I have a Dell Inspiron 7375 (it's a 2 in 1). It comes with an AMD Ryzen 7 and there's no gpu, it has it's own integrated graphics. I've been running in some trouble while installing Kubuntu/trying to boot ubuntu and I've been finding it hard to find a fix/have had a hard time following them.

The error message that popped onto my screen was:

> Firmware Bug: IOAPIC[4] not in IVRS table, No southbridge IOAPIC found,
>   ACPI BIOS Error Could not resolve [\SB.PCI0.LPC0.EC0].

I have shortened down a bit to make it easier to type. If you know how to solve this it would be very appreciated! And before I forget to say, I have not been able to boot to Ubuntu before and I am trying to run a dual boot with Windows 10 if that's also important, I have it set to the UEFI boot mode, and previously I have gotten Manjaro Linux to work.

Lastly, I currently have fast boot disabled.

Comment: You haven't said what release of Kubuntu you are trying to boot, nor which software stack you were trying (applies to LTS releases which have two+ options).   I would suggest later releases (with latest HWE if LTS), plus verify your ISO download, and write to media. I'd have possibly been more specific but I don't even know what you tried to boot as you were unspecific (*only a Kubuntu of unknown year/release*)

Comment: IF firmware related, do you have latest UEFI from Dell?  See also https://superuser.com/questions/1052023/ioapic0-not-in-ivrs-table & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2254677

Comment: I have updated my Bios (many times) from what Dell offered prior to trying to install Kubuntu 19.04. It seems to me that my laptop is currently up to date with all the drivers, however, I could check again. I'm not sure whether this version supports LTS or HWE but now that you mention it, I'll definitely look for a version with it.